# Implements undoable command - Java

Tags: java, model-view-controller, design-patterns, memento

I'm currently programming a little text editor (project for school) and I'm having some troubles finding a good and clean way to manage the undoable commands.

(It is not a code review question as it's not only about improvement. I need to change my code if I want my application to work as I want it to)

Here's how my application works: I have a concrete subject that holds the buffer that is actually an arraylist of characters. Whenever this arraylist is modified (insertion, cut, paste...), the subject updates the observers - which consist in only one gui for the moment - (MVC pattern).

What I was doing until now for the undo and redo was saving the whole state of the buffer (through a memento), which is working fine but:

- could obviously be improved.
- is not working for the new feature that I need to implement (recording user actions so he can play them back whenever he wants to)

I can't figure out how to save the commands instead of the buffer, and if it is the good way to go.

Here's some chunks of the program (for the insert command):

**"GUI".java**

```
...

class KeyboardListener extends KeyAdapter { 

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            ...
            commandManager.executeCommandInsert(caretStart, caretStop, e.getKeyChar());
            ...
    }
    ...
}
```

**CommandManager.java**

```
...

public void executeCommandInsert(int start, int end, char character) {  
    addMementoUndo();   
    commandInsert.setCarets(start, end);
    commandInsert.setChar(character);
    commandInsert.execute();    
}

public void addMementoUndo() 
{
    TextConcrete text = TextConcrete.getInstance();
    this.commandsUndo.add(0, text.createMemento());
    if(recordMode){
        this.recordings.add(text.createMemento());
    }
}
...
```

**CommandInsert.java**

```
...
public void execute(){
   TextConcrete text = TextConcrete.getInstance();
   text.insert(this.start, this.end, this.character);
}
...
```

**TextConcrete.java**

```
...
public void insert(int start, int end, char character){
    //inserting in ArrayList
}

public CommandUndoable createMemento(){
   CommandUndoable mem = new CommandUndoable();
   mem.setState(getState());
   return mem;
}

public String getState(){
   StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
   for(int idx = 0; idx < this.state.size(); idx++){
       temp.append(this.state.get(idx));
   }    
   return temp.toString();
}
...
```

The CommandUndoable is just the memento that save the state of the buffer and then is saved in a list of memento in the CareTaker (CommandManager).

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: there are a lot of different ways to implement undo/redo/replay.  The most common one is to use the "Command" design pattern, which you may want to read about (you mentionned "memento" but it's not clear if you refer to the design pattern, for the memento pattern is typically **not** the one to use for undo/redo/replay).  If/when you're doing OO over immutable objects you can implement and undo/redo in a much simpler way, by trivially saving the entire state but this "wastes" memory.

Comment: Yes I'm using a Command Pattern (a Command interface and then all Commands as separate objects). Well the memento was the way to go to save the whole buffer, but now I'm kind of lost about how to create a new implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a *Undoable* interface that commands can implement such as:

```
public interface Undoable {

   public void do(Editor text)

   public void undo(Editor text)

}
```

where *Editor* is the model of your editor that you can insert text into, remove text from, or manipulate with other commands.  A command implementing the interface only needs to know how to 'do' and 'undo' itself, so you do not need to store a copy of the text buffer at each step, just store a *List* of the commands.

Comment: and then you would just save `this` in the list?

Comment: Have a separate CommandHandler class that handles the undo/redo mechanism.

Comment: I read in the book _Patterns in Java_ by Mark Grand a solution similar to yours that I just adapted a little bit and it's working now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to define two interfaces, but without any arguments in their methods

```
public interface Command {

    public void execute();

}
```

... and for Undo Actions:

```
 public interface UndoableCommand extends Command  {

    public void undo();

}
```

I think, this is more flexible, because you may have some interactions in your application that are not Undoable. (Like saving or loading a file)

To implement such a `UndoableCommand` just write somethink like that..

```
 public class EditorInsertCommand implements UndoableCommand  {

    private Editor editor;

    private String textToInsert;

    private String textBefore;

    public EditorInsertCommand(Editor editor, String textToInsert){
       this.editor = editor;
       this.textToInsert = textToInsert;
    }


    public void execute() {
        this.textBefore = editor.getText();
        editor.setText(textToInsert);
    };

    public void undo(){
       editor.setText(textBefore );
    };

}
```

The handling of `execute` and `undo`, can be done via a `CommandManager` as well.

Comment: Yes but aren't you still saving the whole buffer with that method? (`textBefore`)

Comment: You are free to implement this on logic. This is even the simplest way to do. I just wanted to show the usage of the `Command` and `UndoableCommand` interfaces

Comment: That's correct, he is. Because of this I would not save the whole textBefore but the position where the insert happend and the inserted text. So instead of replacing the whole Text an Undo should cut the inserted text from the modified text.